# How does Wolfram Alpha solve functional equations?

Tags: mathematical-programming

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) is able to solve a few basic functional equations. For example, it knows how to solve equations like [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29%2Bf%28y%29%3Df%28x%2By%29). My question is: how does it do this? I am planning on creating a program to find solutions to functional equations (doesn't have to be anything too fancy -- start with just testing for polynomial solutions, etc.).

Note: By "functional equation" I mean [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FunctionalEquation.html).

Comment: Have you taken a look at the references on the page you link to?  Based on the titles a few of them seem relevant.

Comment: @D.W. I have, none of the references accessible to me seem fruitful for my cause. It may be true that I am missing one that might be helpful, if that is the case could you please point me towards that specific one?

Comment: Try looking at Mathematica docs for this functionality. If you can't find it, ask a question on Mathematica SE. But is your question about how to do this on a computer in general, or specifically how Mathematica does it?

Comment: @Juho I can't find this specific functionality in the Wolfram Language Docs, rather the Wolfram Mathworld Document (which I linked). I'm asking about a computer in general (the Wolfram example was just to show that it is possible).

Comment: Could you summarize in the question what research you've done and what you've found so far?  If there are some references whose title sound relevant but actually aren't useful, it would be useful to explain why.  If there are some whose title sound relevant but you haven't been able to find them, it would be helpful to mention that.  That will save us from repeating work you've already done or could do on  your own, and make it more likely that this will be useful to others in the future.

Comment: In particular, I see references with titles like "Solving a Functional Equation" and "A Package for Symbolic Solution of Functional Equations", which at least from the title sound like they might be very relevant.  Can you summarize what they say in your question?  More broadly, I suggest you do a literature search using [standard techniques](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8316/351).  Even if you can't find a copy of the paper, those references can help [seed your literature search](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/102411/705).

Comment: @D.W. I just did a bit more research on the author and found this book: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F11758525_56, which seems to perfectly address my cause. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Cool, I hope it helps.  If you figure out an answer to your question, it'd be great to come back and write an answer to your own question summarizing what you've learned.

Comment: @D.W. Will do, thanks.

Comment: Posts on Stack Exchange must stand on their own, and must be fully understandable and answerable without following any links or any external resources. Right now, I cannot even figure out what you are asking. What is this "this" that you are talking about?

Comment: @JörgWMittag He is referring to the functional equation: $\forall x,y: f(x)+f(y)=f(x+y)$ where the task is to find which functions $f$ satisfy those constraints.

Comment: @nirshahar, perhaps I could encourage you to edit the question to make it clearer?  We'd prefer that questions stand on their own rather than having to be explained in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't know how Mathematica solves all such cases, it's worth noting that you need to impose some conditions on Cauchy's functional equation $f(x) + f(y) = f(x+y)$ for it to have a unique solution, such as that $f$ is continuous.

Nonetheless, what's probably going on in this case is that Mathematica turned the system into a recurrence, solved that, and then tested to see if that solution also works on negative numbers, rationals and reals.

Let me show you what I mean. Consider the (more complex) functional equation:

$$f(x+y) + f(x-y) = 2\left[ f(x) + f(y) \right]$$

Set $x = y = 0$ to find:

$$2 f(0) = 4 f(x) \Rightarrow f(0) = 0$$

Set $x=n$ and $y=1$ to find:

$$f(n+1) + f(n-1) = 2\left[ f(n) + f(1) \right]$$
$$\Rightarrow f(n+1) = 2f(n) - f(n-1) + 2f(1)$$

Assuming that $f(1)$ is a free constant, what we have now is a linear inhomogeneous recurrence, and there are well-known reasonably mechanical ways to solve these. Once you've found a potential most-general solution for natural numbers, test to see if the solution is still true for negative numbers, rationals, and reals.

In the cause of the Cauchy functional equation, set $x = y = 0$ to find:

$$2f(0) = f(0) \Rightarrow f(0) = 0$$

and set $x=n$ and $y=1$ to find:

$$f(n + 1) = f(n) + f(1)$$

I'll leave the rest as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks so much! This makes a lot of sense. In the case with $3$ or more variables, the recurrence solution would still work with this method (you just need a few more substitutions at the beginning).